# Set the file name and open blob word type

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to download word document, it is working but i am not how to set file name. Every time it is downloading with some unique name.

```
 this.downloadData("downloadVehicleLine").subscribe(
      data => {
       this.downLoadFile(data);   
      })

downLoadFile(data: any) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var pwa = window.open(url, "createdocument.docx");
    if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed == 'undefined') {
        alert('Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.');
     }

}
```

It should download word document with the name **createdocument.docx**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use an **anchor** element reference instead of `window.URL`; because you can set the name of the file to `download` property of the element.

You can use this code to download files:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// set the name of the file
link.download = "createdocument.docx";
// clicking the anchor element will download the file
link.click();
```

Comment: I tried this but getting my doc content corrupt can anyone help me ?